# NSAttributedString from localized string with format specifier

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, localization, format, nsattributedstring

I have a localized string:

```
"%@ some text" = "%@ some text";
```

The format specifier `%@` may appear in any location in the localized string.

The problem is this string should be an `NSAttributedString`; the `%@` replacement and the rest of the text should have different attributes. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524874/are-there-any-analogues-of-nsstring-stringwithformat-for-nsattributedstring ?

Comment: `NSAttributedString+VPAttributedFormat` seems to be okay but it contains a lot of extra code - categories for UI components

Comment: Try to take or inspire you from the parts that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Get your localized template using `NSLocalizedString()`.
2) Get the text to insert.
3) Combine the two using `-stringWithFormat:`.
4) In the template, find the location of the placeholder using `-rangeOfString:`
5) Find the range of the inserted text in the formatted string, using the start position found in the last step, with `-rangeOfString:options:range:`. (The third argument here is the range within which to search; this avoids finding non-substituted text.)
6) Create an attributed string from the formatted string, using the range to apply attributes to the inserted text.

Comment: It won't work if localized template already contains text to insert before step 2. For example: insert "Hello" into "Hello world! %@". My current solution is similar but I create string attributes for "%@" substring and save its range. Then when I insert string - this range changes its length param only.

Comment: I'll amend, @VyachaslavGerchicov

Answer (score -3):

You can use `NSMutableAttributedString` for this case. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring) is Apple documentation

```
 NSString *textToDisplay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ somet text",localizedString];
 NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textToDisplay];
       [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                       value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo2-Regular" size:30]
                       range:NSMakeRange(0, locatilzedString.length)];
       [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                       value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo2-Bold" size:30]
                       range:NSMakeRange(locatilzedString.length, attrStr.length)];

label.attributedText = attrStr
```

Comment: I changed my answer, you can try this.

Comment: read the question carefully - %@ may appear in the beggining, in the middle and in the end of the format string after localization. You have also missed localization code at all.