# How do I use an attributed string inside a formatted string?

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsattributedstring

So I have a formatted `String` that looks like this:

```
let myString = String(format: "%@ %@ \n\n", "App Version:".makeBold(), AppSettings.appVersion)

//Extension looks like this
extension String {
    func makeBold() -> NSAttributedString {
        let attribute: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont.OpenSansStyle.bold
        ]
        
        return NSAttributedString(string: self, attributes: attribute)
    }
}
```

Now, this obviously dosn't work since it returns an `NSAttributed String` in the middle of a regular `String`. But how do I make this happen? I need to have the `String(format:)` to arrange the values in the correct way. But at the same time I need part of the text to be bold.

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524874/are-there-any-analogues-of-nsstring-stringwithformat-for-nsattributedstring

Comment: Oh that's really nice! Thanks for directing me @m1sh0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [StringEx](https://github.com/andruvs/StringEx) library I wrote for this purpose. It allows html tags to be used in the template string, which makes the code more readable:

```
// Suppose you have a pattern like this
let pattern = "<label /> <value />\n\n"

// Create StringEx instance
let ex = pattern.ex

// Insert values and style
ex[.tag("label")]
    .insert("App Version:")
    .style(.font(.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)))

ex[.tag("value")].insert(AppSettings.appVersion)

// Then you can get the result string or NSAttributedString
let string = ex.string
let attributedString = ex.attributedString

myLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

You can read more about the library's capabilities from the [documentation](https://github.com/andruvs/StringEx#stringex).